# Change the background of the radio button depending by the answer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a mini quiz, if the answer is correct the background will be green, if is wrong will be red

here is the code of HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


<form class="forma">



      <div class="pyetja"><h3>1. The flag if Italy which color has..</h3>

    <div class="formafoto"><div class="foto"></div><div class="pergjigjet"><div class="pergjigje">
                    <div class="pergjigjemajtas">
                    white and blue
                    </div>
                    <div class="pergjigjedjathtas" id="0">
                    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="0" unchecked="">right</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="0" unchecked="">wrong</label>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pergjigje">
                    <div class="pergjigjemajtas">
                    white and red
                    </div>
                    <div class="pergjigjedjathtas" id="1">
                    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="1" unchecked="">right</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="1" unchecked="">wrong</label>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pergjigjeno">
                    <div class="pergjigjemajtas">
                    white red and green
                    </div>
                    <div class="pergjigjedjathtas" id="2">
                    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="2" unchecked="">right</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="2" unchecked="">wrong</label>
                    </div>


    </div></div></div></div>



   <div class="question">   
<input id="buton" type="button" value="Finish!" onClick="getScore(this.form); getResult(this.form);">
<p> <strong class="bgclr">Result = </strong><strong><input  class="bgclr1" type="text" size="2" name="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
<div id="rezultati"></div>
   </div>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and javascript

```
// Insert number of questions
    var numQues = 3;

    // Insert number of choices in each question
    var numChoi = 2;

    // Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
    var answers = new Array(2);

    // Insert answers to questions

    answers[0] = 1;
    answers[1] = 1;
    answers[2] = 1;


    // Do not change anything below here ...
    function getScore(form) {

      var score = 0;
      var currElt;
      var currSelection;
      for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
        currElt = i*numChoi;
        for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
          currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
          if (currSelection.checked) {
            if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
              score++;

          }
        }
       }
      }

            var radio1 = document.getElementByName("0").value;

            if (answers[0] == radio1) {

                    document.getElementById("0").style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";

                     } else {

                    document.getElementById("0").style.backgroundColor="#e83f3f";

                     }



                if(score > 3) {
                        document.getElementById("rezultati").innerHTML = "Congratulation!";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("rezultati").innerHTML = "Try again!";
                    }


      form.percentage.value = score;

      form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

    }
    //  End -->
    </script>
```

I get always red background and if the answer is correct, maybe document.getElementByName("0").value is not getting a number to make true the condition

```
var radio1 = document.getElementByName("0").value;

            if (answers[0] == radio1) {

                document.getElementById("0").style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";

            } else {

                document.getElementById("0").style.backgroundColor="#e83f3f";

             }
```

Comment: there are many mistakes in your code. when you are getting an element with id "0" it will return a div and it will not have any value. you need to get the radio buttons by giving them an id/name and check if they are checked. If they are checked you need to use that value as user selected value.

Comment: im trying to get a value from a name which is at 
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="1" unchecked="">right</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="1" unchecked="">wrong</label>

The radio button has name and value, for what need id there?

Comment: i think function name is getElementsByName and it will return you an array of elements.

Comment: i think that document.getElementByName("0").value is not getting a number but a String, its a way to turn it as number?

Comment: assign getElementsByName("1") to a variable and loop through it to check which dom element is checked like if(x[i].checked). if checked, take that value and compare it to answers[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
 var radio1 = document.getElementByName("0").value;

            if (answers[0] == radio1) {
```

Probably your error is in this line of code, the id="0" is a div and you are trying to get the value of it, this might result into undefined and the value answer[0] is 1, thus 1 is not equal to radio1, thus it is always getting into the else block.

Comment: Its var radio1 = document.getElementByName("0").value; and still its not working...

Comment: i think that document.getElementByName("0").value is not getting a number but a String, its a way to turn it as number?

Comment: Its var radio1 = document.getElementsByName("0") which will give an array of all elements with name "0" like [<input type="" name="0">,<input type="" name="0">], we might need to check the value of these radio buttons, this might help `var radio1 = document.getElementsByName("0")[0].value`

Comment: #Ekansh good point, but now is making green like correct even a wrong answer. Any idea...

Comment: check the answers you provided in the questions and in answers[] array

Comment: i didnt get what you are trying to ask

Comment: var radio1 = document.getElementsByName("0") will be giving you to elements   `<input type="radio" value="1" name="0" unchecked="">and <input type="radio" value="0" name="0" unchecked=""> just check that if the radio button is checked before changing the color like if(document.getElementsByName("0")[0].checked == true){green}, just check the synatx, i might be wrong with the syntax, but this will make the things work

Comment: Thanks Ekansh, your answer was valid, its working great!

Comment: well in that case you can mark it as a correct answer